# Diferentes resultados ao extrair subset de uma tibble

Tags: r

Eu tenho uma [tibble](https://drive.google.com/file/d/160FQYRa2N_HWSAR67KmV-_sOwUrOLz0N/view?usp=sharing) de 3.358.512 linhas por 8 colunas e estou fazendo limpeza e exploração nos dados e percebi, sem querer, um comportamento que me chamou a atenção.
Se eu executar o seguinte código:

`subset(SARS_BR, ANO == "2108")`

O resultado é o esperado abaixo:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 8
  DT_ENCERRA CLASSI_FIN EVOLUCAO CS_SEXO SG_UF_NOT IDADE MES     ANO  
  <date>     <fct>      <fct>    <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1 2108-12-22 4          1        M       PA          107 12-2108 2108
```

A função filter do pacote dplyr dá o mesmo resultado:

```
> dplyr::filter(SARS_BR, ANO == "2108")
# A tibble: 1 × 8
  DT_ENCERRA CLASSI_FIN EVOLUCAO CS_SEXO SG_UF_NOT IDADE MES     ANO  
  <date>     <fct>      <fct>    <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1 2108-12-22 4          1        M       PA          107 12-2108 2108
```

Porém ao fazer o subset de forma que eu possa manipular a informação, neste caso específico o ano é 2018 e não 2108.
O que acontece é estranho para mim e não me recordo de ter visto este comportamento antes:

```
> SARS_BR[SARS_BR$ANO == "2108",]
# A tibble: 378,865 × 8
   DT_ENCERRA CLASSI_FIN EVOLUCAO CS_SEXO SG_UF_NOT IDADE MES   ANO  
   <date>     <fct>      <fct>    <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
 2 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
 3 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
 4 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
 5 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
 6 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
 7 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
 8 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
 9 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
10 NA         NA         NA       NA      NA           NA NA    NA   
# … with 378,855 more rows
```

Confesso que não sei o que estou fazendo de errado para obter esse resultado utilizando colchetes para o subset. O "padrão" se repete para outras variáveis, o número de resultados é o mesmo com subset ou dply::filter e outro cheio de NAs com os colchetes. Desconfio que os NAs (da tabela original e não os gerados no resultado) estão interferindo, mas não tenho certeza de como.

Alguma ideia do que eu estou deixando passar?

Grato pela atenção.

Comment: O que é que `any(SARS_BR$ANO == "2108")`, `unique(SARS_BR$ANO == "2108")` e `unique(SARS_BR$ANO)` dão?

Comment: O ficheiro tem a extensão Rds, foi criado co que função do R?

Comment: É importante ressaltar que alguns operadores (como o `[`, `$` e o `[[`) não funcionam com objetos de classe `tibble` da mesma forma que funcionam para um `data.frame`. Veja [aqui](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html).

Comment: @RuiBarradas foi savo com a função saveRDS(), a tabela foi importada ao R com a função readr::read_csv2() a partir de uma URL. Mas vi sua resposta abaixo e ela resolve e esclarece a situação. Obrigado.

Comment: @neves Verdade. As tibbles são novidade para mim. Achei o conceito interessante e dentro do possível estou tentando utilizá-las ao invés dos data.frames. Mas possuo estruturas de dados que necessitam de rownames, por exemplo, aí volto pros data.frames.

Answer (score 4):

O problema está na forma como os operadores de comparação tratam os `NA` (e `NaN`). De `help("Comparison")` ou `help("==")`.

> Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA. Missing values can also result when character strings are compared and one is not valid in the current collation locale.

Tradução Google Translate, editada por mim.

> Os valores em falta (NA) e os valores NaN são considerados não comparáveis ​​até a si mesmos, portanto, comparações envolvendo-os sempre resultarão em NA. Valores em falta também podem ocorrer quando as cadeias de caracteres são comparadas e uma não é válida na localidade de agrupamento atual.

Ou seja, o resultado da comparação tem 378K valores `NA`.

```
na <- is.na(SARS_BR$ANO == "2108")
sum(na)
#[1] 378864
```

e cada um deles vai extrair uma linha com todos os valores das colunas `NA`.

```
nrow(SARS_BR[SARS_BR$ANO == "2108", ])
#[1] 378865
```

A solução é usar `which`.

```
i <- which(SARS_BR$ANO == "2108")
SARS_BR[i, ]
## A tibble: 1 x 8
#  DT_ENCERRA CLASSI_FIN EVOLUCAO CS_SEXO SG_UF_NOT IDADE MES     ANO  
#  <date>     <fct>      <fct>    <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
#1 2108-12-22 4          1        M       PA          107 12-2108 2108
```

Ou diretamente

```
SARS_BR[which(SARS_BR$ANO == "2108"), ]
## A tibble: 1 x 8
#  DT_ENCERRA CLASSI_FIN EVOLUCAO CS_SEXO SG_UF_NOT IDADE MES     ANO  
#  <date>     <fct>      <fct>    <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
#1 2108-12-22 4          1        M       PA          107 12-2108 2108
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Por curiosidade, sabe me dizer se o R sempre trabalhou assim? Eu usava versões muito antigas dele e estou retornando agora nas versões 4.x. Não me recordo desse comportamento (que faz sentido aliás).

Comment: @Rodrigo Sim, tanto quanto me lembro o R sempre funcionou assim. De um modo geral é preciso ter cuidado com os `NA`'s. Em vez de `which`, outra opção é `%in%`.